# Do not halt the boot if an fstab mounting fails

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, sshfs

I have this line in my fstab:

```
sshfs#ecarroll@o99:/opt/dealermade/ftp/inc /opt/dealermade/ftp/inc fuse defaults,idmap=user,users 0 0
```

For whatever reason it didn't work -- that's fine. How do I make it not stop the boot sequence. It prompted me to to hit <kbd>S</kbd> to skip or <kbd>M</kbd> to manually repair. If it isn't the boot volume, I just want my volumes to fail mounting with nothing more than an entry in logs.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not familiar with sshfs, but I know the `nobootwait` option works for local disk partitions.  Maybe try:

```
sshfs#ecarroll@o99:/opt/dealermade/ftp/inc /opt/dealermade/ftp/inc fuse defaults,idmap=user,users,nobootwait 0 0
```

(A quick google search also shows archlinux uses `nofail` as per [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=114856) thread.  A little more googling shows that `nobootwait` might be a non-standard Ubuntu feature...  curious to see if it resolves your issue. )

Comment: `nofail` did not resolve the issue, `nobootwait` did.

Comment: [The difference between nofail, and nobootwait can be found on this question.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53456/3285)

Comment: For me, `nofail` worked for an USB drive on Debian 8. My system failed to boot before when it wasn't connected, now it ignores the error.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu deprecated `nobootwait`.

Answer (score 3):

nobootwait worked very well for me in Linux Mint until version 18.  I miss it.

Using nobootwait could result in writing to your OS drive rather than a mounted drive, but only if you are careless.  If you always write to a folder on your mount, then if the mount fails the folder will not exist and the write fails.

Comment: You can also mitigate this problem by doing `chattr +i /the/mount/point` to deny every user (even root) access to the directory if nothing is mounted on it.

Comment: This is a very interesting comment. But in case you come accross `lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl` it means that your filesystem does not support it.

Comment: @samhocevar just stumbled across this, and noticed your comment.  I have tended to do "chmod 000" on my (network) mountpoints for the same reasons, it seems to work, and is very obvious in a full directory listing whether the mount is active.  Are there any gotchas with my approach?

Comment: @m4r35n357 `chmod 000` will not prevent root from accessing the directory; it may not turn out to be a problem, but be aware of that difference.

Comment: @samhocevar THX for the response.  Not a problem for me, as there is nothing in there to access (unless I want trouble!), it is just a nice, simple, filesystem-level indication whether a mount point is in use.  Have you tried it?