# What is the difference between 'nobootwait' and 'nofail' in fstab?

Tags: fstab

In [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53377/3285) I asked how to prevent a media failure from halting the system boot process. However, I got two suggestions for `/etc/fstab` options

- `nobootwait`
- `nofail`

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Note that Ubuntu deprecated `nobootwait`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Firstly `nofail` allows the boot sequence to continue even if the drive fails to mount.**

This is what `fstab(5)` says about **`nobootwait`**

> The  mountall(8) program that mounts filesystem during boot also recognises additional options that the  ordinary  mount(8)  tool  does  not. These  are:
>
> - `bootwait`  which  can  be applied to remote filesystems
>   mounted outside of /usr or /var, without which  mountall(8)  would  not hold up the boot for these;
> - `nobootwait` which can be applied to
>   non-remote filesystems to explicitly instruct mountall(8) not  to  hold  up the boot for them;
> - `optional` which causes the entry to be ignored if the filesystem type is not known  at  boot  time;  and
> - `showthrough`
>   which  permits  a mountpoint to be mounted before its parent mountpoint (this latter should be used carefully, as it can cause boot hangs).

`fstab(5)` has this to say about **`nofail`**

> `nofail` do not report errors for  this  device  if  it  does  not
> exist.

Comment: Note that mountall and those options are ubuntu (and its derivatives) specific (and only relatively recent versions where upstart and that mountall was introduced.

Comment: `nobootwait` is no longer a valid option in Ubuntu 16.04 (as of 2016-07-10 testing Mythbuntu install/live-DVD).

Comment: `External devices that are to be mounted when present but ignored if absent may require the nofail option. This prevents errors being reported at boot.`

Comment: EvanCarroll: Can you address @endolith's comment?

Comment: @Mehrdad They're not my definitions. They're cited definitions, I have no control over them. My statement is that "nofail does not permit the boot sequence to continue if the drive fails to mount." You can see the example that caused [this investigation here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53377/3285).

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Could you provide a link to them? It's not clear to me where you might have pulled these from...

Comment: i say quite explicitly `fstab(5)`. So `man 5 fstab`

Comment: @EvanCarroll which distribution did you look up man 5 fstab on? E.g. Ubuntu 16 LTS does not mention nobootwait or bootwait at all.

Comment: @ILIV http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/fstab.5.html not sure if it was a sysv or ubuntu patch or what.

Comment: I see, that's Ubuntu 14 (Trusty). Thank you @EvanCarroll. Just to confirm what Kingsley said above bootwait/nobootwait is no longer supported on Ubuntu 16 LTS. Only nofail.

Comment: When I tried to use `nofail` I got unrecognized option `errors=nofail`

Answer (score 38):

Since this old question has a high Google rating, I'll mention that since "nobootwait" doesn't work with systemd, the correct method is to set a short timeout of, say, 9 seconds with "x-systemd.device-timeout".

e.g.:

```
/dev/sda2  /mnt/other  auto  defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=9  0  2
```

(Edit: I've increased the timeout from 3s to 9s because it seems that Ubuntu occasionally does a quick filesystem-check on bootup that can last longer than 3s.)

Answer (score 31):

As mentioned by Stéphane, nobootwait is limited to ubuntu+derivatives.

Nofail will keep trying to mount the drive as cjm pointed out, however, the **boot process will continue after the mount reaches timeout**. 
If you don't expect the drive to be there regularly as to warrant the extra 90 seconds or so bootup when it's absent, don't automount it in fstab.

(P.S. I put this as cjm's answer sounds as if the system will ultimately *fail* to boot).

Answer (score 6):

This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170707005942/http://techmonks.net/nofail-and-nobootwait-mount-options-in-fstab-prevent-boot-problems/) seems to explain the difference well.

> mountall tries to automount all entries from fstab that have the defaults or auto mount options. It will halt the boot process if such entries cannot be mounted, except when the mount option `nobootwait` is given.
>
> fsck tries to do a filesystem check on all entries from fstab that have the sixth field set to 1 or 2. Non-critical drives typically have this field set to 2. It will halt the boot process if such filesystems cannot be checked, except when the mount option `nofail` is given.

Disclaimer: I am not a fstab expert and cannot guarantee/verify the above information to be true. All credits belong to the [author of that article](http://techmonks.net/authors/evert/).

Comment: When I tried to use `nofail` I got unrecognized option `errors=nofail`

Comment: Article seems to be dead. Here's a link to archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20170707005942/http://techmonks.net/nofail-and-nobootwait-mount-options-in-fstab-prevent-boot-problems/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, below are the mount options added into the ubuntu-20.4 `/etc/fstab` file. I was able to mount without any error.

```
UUID=297e42c4-436d-4218-953e-f2681ff7df8c /raid  ext4    errors=remount-ro,nofail  0   1
```